# Word suggestion - "empty" vs "blank"

Tags: usability, forms, labels, text

Have a question as to what makes more sense... we have a "visual search" component which allows users to type in a category (column header) and then type in what they are looking for (e.g. First Name: John) and it would spit out the results.

We want to have an option for "null"... we are debating on "Empty" vs "Blank". Therefore a user could select First Name: then the word "Blank" or "Empty" (e.g. First Name: Blank, First Name: Empty).

What is a better name to use? Blank or Empty? Any other suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a perfect question for http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Do you mean that the user can specifically search for blank fields, as in finding people with no middle names? Or are they searching for fields that have missing data?

Comment: @timster I don't see why that would be a problem. My answer had nothing to do with database concepts and all SE users have a mix of interests and expertise.

Comment: This is under the assumption that there are fields of "first name" that have no data value; therefore, they are "empty" or "blank". Does "empty" convey that there is no data value? Does "blank" convey there is no data value?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but when the first name field in this case "has no data value," is that because those people are known to have no first names, or is it because their first names are unknown?

Comment: First name is a bad example because that is usually required, but let's say it's not for the sake of this example. It's because their first names are unknown (aka not filled out).

Comment: @timster At the database level that would be the difference between null and empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the context in which you are attempting to use these terms I think blank and empty would be synonyms. Although empty seems a tad more suitable.

> [***blank***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blank) (adjective) - not written or printed on.
>
> [***empty***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/empty) (adjective) - containing nothing; not filled or occupied.

However, I think the meaning of both don't exactly fit with your scenario. In your workflow the user is searching for instances where the category matches what they enter in the field. The null option is used when *First Name* has nothing in it. As used here, empty and blank would be adjectives i.e. they describe the state of the field and not what is in it.

For this reason I think the best word would be ***Nothing***.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think about it like that. How about instead of a word, we used "--", indicating a null field?

Comment: It's always best to be explicit but that could work.

Comment: Alright thank you for the response. I have some things to mull over now :)

Comment: I agree with everything but your last paragraph.

Comment: @Devin what word would you recommend?

Comment: @AndreDickson would it be "safer" to use "--" or explicitly providing a word? I will ask this question on english.stackexchange.com too

Comment: @bobbyo23 a word is potentially safer because it is more explicit. Of course if you choose a word that is vague or incorrect you lose this benefit.

Comment: Same as you said, both of them seems more or less the same, with *empty* seeming like a tad better option. However, *nothing* is a **charged** word, hence why I'd avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Our users are attorneys and the seem to understand "empty"
Tried "null" and they did not like that
For anything they search on "not empty"

For engineers null works fine

Comment: you tried _null?_

Comment: What is the purpose of that question?

Comment: "Null" is not a great output, even for engineers. It looks like your code might be failing at retrieving data rather than an invitation to search or edit.

Comment: @Shadetheartist I said TRIED and they did not like that.  You comments are not constructive.   Comments are for clarification.  I don't have a question here.

Answer (score 1):

#### You’re asking this question because neither term quite feels right.

(And that's your queue to keep going.)

If this app is for general population users (that is, not database users) then “blank” or “empty” may not be quite what you need: these are words that describe the **data field.** Users don't think in terms of data fields, unless software forces them to. They'd rather work with “information” than with “data.”

### User Story Fill-in-the-Blank

Considering the following user story:

```
“Show me customers whose middle names are ______”
```

If we finish the sentence with "blank" or "empty" here, the sentence sounds a little odd. That's because the middle names are not blank or empty — the database field is.

I’d suggest terms that more naturally complete the user case above would be better candidates, for example, **missing** or **not provided.** (Google uses "not provided" in for these cases in Google Analytics.)

Comment: This is really good reasoning. Our application is targeted for higher education institutes. Our personas are those of older age. I like where you are going with this considering the user story rather than an analytical sense of data structure. "Not provided" seems better to me than "missing" as I read it as a user story.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I suggest "not specified" or just "-". I find these solutions a more natural language.

Also, "NA" (in data science field means "No Answer") is a standard terminology for null data in data industry, but in this case I think is less indicated.

Other solution can be to design different states for the fields. If it is not filled, you can make it look disabled.

Personally, I'd use "-".